# Time Derivative of Vector Connecting a Pair of Parallel Lines

Tags: geometry

I have a pair of parallel (or close to parallel) lines in 3D space. Each line is attached to a distinct rigid body. The two rigid bodies are rotating about their centre of mass. Lets make the lines:
$$\boldsymbol  l_1 = \boldsymbol p_1 + s*\boldsymbol d_1\\
\boldsymbol  l_2 = \boldsymbol p_2 + t*\boldsymbol d_2$$

and have them rotate at $\boldsymbol w_1$ and $\boldsymbol w_2$ rad/s about the centres of mass $\boldsymbol com_1$ and $\boldsymbol com_2$.

I would like to find the time derivative of the normalised vector between these two lines.

For the skew line case I already have the below. Its obviously a bad idea to divide by $\mid \boldsymbol d_1 \times \boldsymbol d_2 \mid$ for parallel lines, but I will show the derivation for skew lines in the hope it will help with my bad explanations.

For two skew lines the normalised vector between them is 
$$\boldsymbol  n = (\boldsymbol d_1 \times \boldsymbol d_2) /  q \\
q = \mid \boldsymbol d_1 \times \boldsymbol d_2 \mid$$

Taking the time derivative of this we get:
$$
\frac{dn}{dt} = \frac{q((\dot{\boldsymbol d_1} \times \boldsymbol d_2) + (\boldsymbol d_1 \times \dot{\boldsymbol d_2})) - \dot q(\boldsymbol d_1 \times \boldsymbol d_2)}{q^2}\\
= \frac{((\dot{\boldsymbol d_1} \times \boldsymbol d_2) + (\boldsymbol d_1 \times \dot{\boldsymbol d_2})) - \dot q*\boldsymbol n}{q}
$$
We know that $q^2= (\boldsymbol d_1 \times \boldsymbol d_2) \cdot (\boldsymbol d_1 \times \boldsymbol d_2)$ therefore its time derivative is $2*q*\dot q = 2(\boldsymbol d_1 \times \boldsymbol d_2)\cdot ((\dot{\boldsymbol d_1} \times \boldsymbol d_2) + (\boldsymbol d_1 \times \dot{\boldsymbol d_2}))$ and $\dot q = \boldsymbol n \cdot ((\dot{\boldsymbol d_1} \times \boldsymbol d_2) + (\boldsymbol d_1 \times \dot{\boldsymbol d_2}))$. Putting this altogether and using $\dot{\boldsymbol d_i}=\boldsymbol d_i \times \boldsymbol w_i, i = 1,2$

$$
\frac{dn}{dt} = \frac{(\boldsymbol u - (\boldsymbol u \cdot \boldsymbol n) * \boldsymbol n)}{\mid \boldsymbol d_1 \times \boldsymbol d_2 \mid}
\boldsymbol\\
u = (\boldsymbol d_1 \times (\boldsymbol w_1 \times \boldsymbol d_1)) + ((\boldsymbol w_2 \times \boldsymbol d_2) \times \boldsymbol d_2)\\
$$

In case anyone tries this, I find the noramlised vector between two parallel lines by considering a fixed point on line $\boldsymbol l_1$, finding the closest point to it on $\boldsymbol l_2$ and normalising the vector between these two points. Put another way I find the vector between a point and a line. Taking the time derivative of this equation doesn't work because when the lines are rotated about the normal vector there should be no change in this vector. This is not the case for the vector between a point and a line.

Cheers,

Richard

Comment: So $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are vectors? How are you giving $D_1$ and $D_2$? What you've written is very hard to follow.

Comment: hopefully thats a little better now I've learnt some Latex

Comment: Thanks. The LaTeX wasn't the issue. I do not yet follow the math. Are both rotations about axes through the origin? You can't just simply use the cross product. You need points to move on circles in planes orthogonal to the respective $w_j$. Too bad there's no easy formula (without going into quaternions or some such) for the axis of rotation of the product of two rotations (or, in your case, the product of one and the inverse of the other).

Comment: I keep trying, please don’t give up on me yet :)